# How to place percentage orders with Binance API and Python-CCXT?

Tags: python, bitcoin, trading, binance, ccxt

I'm playing with Binance API to make my trading bot with Python 3.6. and [CCXT library](https://github.com/ccxt/ccxt) (here you find the [docs](https://ccxt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) ).

One very useful thing they have in their site is the capability to place orders for a percentage of your current balance:

for example if I'm lookin at `BTC/USDT` crypto coin pair, and I have `50 USDT` on my account, I can choose between buying `N` amount of `BTC` or using `100%` of my account's `USDT` for buying, consequently buying the maximum amount of `BTC` I can.

I read the docs many times, but I can't find the option to do these "percentage of balance" orders with the API in any way: the only thing I can do is passing a `float` to the order function.
This is how i place orders now:

```py
amount = 0.001
symbol = "BTC/USDT"

def buyorder(amount, symbol): # this makes a market order taking in the amount I defined before, for the pair defined by "symbol"

    type = 'market'  # or 'limit'
    side = 'buy'     # or 'sell'
    params = {}      # extra params and overrides if needed
    order = exchange.create_order(symbol, type, side, amount, params)
```

Do anyone know if there is a built-in capability to do 
a percentage order? If API gives no way to do so, would you suggest some workarounds?

I want to be able to give to the API percentage of my current balance as an `amount`, so I can always use the full of it without having to update when fees are detracted

Comment: could you add a link to the API documentation and perhaps some of the code you're having trouble with to give us a better picture of what's going on here and what you need help with exactly?

Comment: seems like the API doesn't allow percentage orders, you can calculate it yourself in the script, getting the free balance before place the order

Answer (score 5):

Use a custom function like this:

```
 def get_max_position_available():
    to_use = float(exchange.fetch_balance().get('USDT').get('free'))
    price = float(exchange.fetchTicker('BTC/USDT').get('last'))
    decide_position_to_use = to_use / price
    return decide_position_to_use
```

Comment: please add context to prevent removal of answer by bots.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know of any Binance API function that does that, but you can try something like this:

```
# You ask for the balance
balance= client.get_asset_balance(asset='USDT')

# set the percentage or fraction you want to invest in each order
portion_balance = float(balance['free']) * 0.35

# you assign the created variable in the quantity of your order
sell_market = client.order_market_sell(
    symbol= 'ETHUSDT',
    quantity= portion_balance)
```

Greetings ;)